Why does the null coalescing operator not work here?
I am trying to better understand how the nullish coalescing operator (??) in JavaScript is supposed to work. Can someone please explain why this:
let a = b ?? 0;

returns this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined

The docs say (emphasis mine):

The nullish coalescing (??) operator is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

Since b is undefined, my expectation is that a will be assigned the value 0.

You need to declare b as a variable. It does not need to be assigned anything, it just needs to exist. For the reverse, the existence of a variable does not mean it has an assigned variable.

It's unfortunate that the word "undefined" means both a state of non-existence of a symbol in an expression, and also an actual value that can be used in expressions. You have no symbol b defined, and therefor a reference to it is an exception, not merely the value undefined.

Also, this operator is typically used when accessing properties that may or may not exist on an object, or destructured properties.

@jonrsharpe - after reading carefully, I agree that the dupe target mostly answers my question. Thank you. It seems this is the only way to get the result I expect: let a = typeof b !== "undefined" ? b : 2;. It's a shame that ?? doesn't handle this the way php does, which is far more useful IMO.

A "not defined" variable is different than a variable with value "undefined"
A variable can be defined, but have a null or undefined value.
If you are sure the variable is not assigned to undefined you can use typeof to check if it is defined:
const a = true;
console.log(typeof a === "undefined"); // false, the "a" variable is defined
console.log(typeof b === "undefined"); // true, the "b" variable is either set to undefined or not defined

A better way would be to refer to the variable, but include it in a try/catch block:
try {
    console.log(someVar);
} catch (error) {
    // if the code goes here, it means that the variable someVar is not defined
}

Conclusion: the ?? operator is not for checking if a variable is defined or not.
